# How to derive pseudo-random values of a preset probability from a seed?

Tags: c++, probability, random-seed

I have a bunch of classes that I'd like to instantiate using *seeds*. Such a class would only have one constructor; taking in a single argument, the seed. A very simple pseudo example could be:

```
class Person {
    int age;
    Person(uint32 seed){
        age = deriveAgeFromSeed(seed);
    }
}
```

If I instantiate a Person with a random given seed, e.g. `123456789`, it should evaluate to a Person with a specific age, e.g `30`. The same seed will always generate the same person (same age).

To achieve this specific example, I could use a regular random-number-generator and use my seed as its seed to generate a random number between e.g. 0-100 for age.
However, I may not want it to be linearly random. Maybe I'd want a 50% chance that the age is in the range of 30-40. I guess I could chain a bunch of "random" numbers operations with my logic, e.g. generating a number from 0 to 1 which would indicate which age-range should be used, and then generate a new number to decide what specific age within this given range. But this would be a very ugly chain of hard code, and very hard to make adjustments to later.

I'd rather want a way to bundle an "option probability set" with the application. For instance an XML file that would specify the probability for all variable. The file could be loaded into memory at launch to prevent having to read the same file every time a person is instantiated. Unrealistic example to give an idea of what I mean:

```
"Person":
    "age": 
        0-30: 25%,
        30-40: 50%,
        40-100: 25%
```

The application would use this information to automagically set an age based on the seed, with these given "probability parameters".
Having such a file would drastically decrease the workload for future adjustments of parameters, and would even let me change parameters without having to rebuild the application. But is it viable?

In addition to this, there may be cases where a second parameter could be dependent on the first. An example could be `enum Occupation`, where certain occupations are more common for certain ages (e.g. 'fast food employee' being more common at younger ages and CEO more common the older they get).

This type of logic seems rather common for certain types of video games, e.g. RTS such as "Civilization", where the game seed would be used to create the map, place its resources and the player spawn locations. It appears to also be used for procedural sandbox games such as Minecraft, where there's a certain probability for biomes. The latter is probably more noise-based, but still, noise would only give an output between 0 and 1, and they somehow derive a certain biome probability from it.

(I will code in C++, but language doesn't matter for the question)

So

1. What is the optimal/best practice procedure to derive many values at preset probabilities from a single seed?
2. Can the probabilities be imported from an external file?
3. Can probabilities be dependent on each other?

Comment: I would start by looking at the different [distributions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) offered by the language. You can always write your own or tweak them if you need to.

Comment: E.g. something like [`std::piecewise_constant_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution) for age, and [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) for picking index of the occupation

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you are thinking about a prng with a state, that you can initialize and use exactly once to generate the age value. However, for this purpose, hash would be also good: it also produces a pseudo-random number with uniform distribution on the given output space. If there is any need to generate a sequence of random numbers from a single seed, then a random number engine would be more useful.
2. XML, JSON and other formats can be read in using 3rd party libraries in C++. However, if the difficulty level is at storing age ranges and probability, for portability and dependency management it can be better to implement the parser yourself.
3. If I am correct, the age distribution is occupation-dependent. Once you derive the correct distribution for the occupation (either explicitly defined in a settings file, like in point 2 or by calculating it using a formula), you can get the right age-distribution from a single pseudo random number generated by the hash function.